# Activate remote desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

We switched to home office work because of quarantine and most users connect to RD over Windows RAS. Some Windows 7 and 10 desktops were used only locally, and RDP was not activated. Now we need to provide RD to all office computers. I can connect to C$. Is it possible to enable remote desktop remotely?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can. There are some prerequisites either WinRM service should run on desktops or AD should be implemented.

For AD via GPO:

1) enable the policy “**Allow users to connect remotely by using Remote Desktop Services**” in “**Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections**”

2) OPTIONAL add ip’s (or subnet) of VPN users to  firewall policy “**Windows Firewall: Allow inbound Remote Desktop exceptions**” in “**Allow users to connect remotely by using Remote Desktop Services” in "Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Network\Network Connections\Windows Firewall\Domain Profile**"

To activate RD without GPO follow the guide - https://www.hyper-v.io/remotely-enable-remote-desktop-another-computer/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried PSEXEC? 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

You can use PSEXEC and run the following:

```
psexec \\COMPUTERNAME reg add "hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\terminal server" /f /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

OR

```
psexec \\COMPUTERNAME -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD reg add "hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\terminal server" /f /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

Very useful for this situation. I have been running into this issue since the quarantine began as well.

I would change the command to fit your current workplace/domain environment, and it is possible to run on all machine within the domain with `\\*` as the computer name if that is the goal. Also note, you will not need to pass a username or password if you are currently running it as the domain administrator.